# Best way to generate an edge table off a datamatrix with Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

I want to generate a graph of genes off a data table. My table T has 2 columns, a column 'ID' and a column 'Genes' with lists in it. The lists contain genes (Strings).

I want my genes as nodes (one node for each gene), and the edges should connect to the two genes, that share one different ID. I tried a lot but i need the fastest solution, because the table has between 700 thousand and 2.7 million rows.

How should i proceed? Like how can i find all appearances of a specific gene in my table?

I have already achieved to generate a nd.array of all mentionend genes. Next i tried to iterate through that list with nd.nditer twice to get all pairwise combinations, and then iterate over all rows to check whether both genes are in one of the lists. Example below.

Next i tried to first transform the table by finding all id's for a specific gene and then go from there. That idea is the second for-loop.

Both aren't very efficient so i am asking if there is a more efficient solution to that problem.

```
for gene1 in nd.nditer(mentionendGenes):
    for gene2 in nd.nditer(mentionendGenes):
        for row in range(0,len(T['ID'])):
            if (gene1 in T['Genes'].values[row]) and (gene2 in T['Genes'].values[row])
                G.add_edge(gene1,gene2)


for gene in np.nditer(mentionendGenes):
    for listofgenes in np.nditer(T['Genes'].values, flags = ['refs_ok']):
        if gene in listofgenes:
            doStuff()
```

Comment: Every time you add edges to an existing graph, you force a copy of the whole graph in memory. Hence you want to add as many edges at once as possible, certainly not one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:

Your first approach can probably be simplified (and sped up) by simply calling

```
import itertools
for row in range(0,len(T['ID'])): 
    G.add_edges_from(itertools.combinations(T['Genes'].values[row], 2))
```

You may find that this can be improved further a bit by getting all edges across all rows first. For proper benchmarking, we would need a decently sized test set.